# gnuplot skipping datapoints close to the axis

Tags: gnuplot

For example in the below plot, data points corresponding to 0-6 and 22-25 are missed. Find the table used to plot the graph below

```
                                        MEM-USAGE-OVER-TIME                       
                         +         +        +         +        +         +     
                   540 +-+-----------------------------------------------+-+   
                         |                                  ******       |     
                   530 +-|                                 *             |-+   
                   520 +-|                                 *             |-+   
                         |                      ***********              |     
                   510 +-|                      *                        |-+   
                   500 +-|                     *                         |-+   
                         |                     *                         |     
              MEM  490 +-|                    *                          |-+   
                         |            *********                          |     
                   480 +-|            *                                  |-+   
                   470 +-|            *                                  |-+   
                         |            *                                  |     
                   460 +-|           *                                   |-+   
                   450 +-|           *                                   |-+   
                         |           *                                   |     
                   440 +-+-----------------------------------------------+-+   
                         +         +        +         +        +         +     
                         0         5        10        15       20        25    
                                       TIME(1unit=10SECONDS)
```

Plotted with using 1:3 w lines

```
1   2707m 442Mi
2   2707m 442Mi
3   2707m 442Mi
4   2707m 442Mi
5   2707m 442Mi
6   2707m 442Mi
7   2384m 486Mi
8   2384m 486Mi
9   2384m 486Mi
10  2384m 486Mi
11  2384m 486Mi
12  2099m 518Mi
13  2099m 518Mi
14  2099m 518Mi
15  2099m 518Mi
16  2099m 518Mi
17  2099m 518Mi
18  2100m 533Mi
19  2100m 533Mi
20  2100m 533Mi
21  2100m 533Mi
```

Any idea of how to get all the data points to get displayed on the plot ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the plot border is drawn after the plot itself. This means that the  points on the plot may be hidden behind the border lines.  To change this so that the border is drawn first:

```
  set border behind
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I expected. I don't want to achieve it with offset or size, since I have a huge set of dynamic data. So, there is son single value of offset or size which satisfies all the different plots.

Comment: Also, thanks for insight that which one is drawn first by default and how to change it.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess this is simply a resolution issue. Increase the vertical size of your terminal (`dumb` I assume) and you probably will see the lines.

**Code:**

```
### dumb terminal size (large enough to show "all" data)
reset session
set term dumb size 80,30

$Data <<EOD
1   2707m 442Mi
2   2707m 442Mi
3   2707m 442Mi
4   2707m 442Mi
5   2707m 442Mi
6   2707m 442Mi
7   2384m 486Mi
8   2384m 486Mi
9   2384m 486Mi
10  2384m 486Mi
11  2384m 486Mi
12  2099m 518Mi
13  2099m 518Mi
14  2099m 518Mi
15  2099m 518Mi
16  2099m 518Mi
17  2099m 518Mi
18  2100m 533Mi
19  2100m 533Mi
20  2100m 533Mi
21  2100m 533Mi
EOD

set key left
plot $Data u 1:3 w l
### end of code
```

**Result:**

```
  540 +---------------------------------------------------------------------+   
      |             +             +             +             +             |   
      |$Data u 1:3 *******                              **********          |   
  530 |-+                                               *                 +-|   
      |                                                *                    |   
  520 |-+                                              *                  +-|   
      |                                 ***************                     |   
      |                                 *                                   |   
  510 |-+                              *                                  +-|   
      |                                *                                    |   
  500 |-+                              *                                  +-|   
      |                               *                                     |   
      |                               *                                     |   
  490 |-+                            *                                    +-|   
      |                   ************                                      |   
      |                   *                                                 |   
  480 |-+                *                                                +-|   
      |                  *                                                  |   
  470 |-+                *                                                +-|   
      |                  *                                                  |   
      |                 *                                                   |   
  460 |-+               *                                                 +-|   
      |                 *                                                   |   
  450 |-+               *                                                 +-|   
      |                *                                                    |   
      |  ***************          +             +             +             |   
  440 +---------------------------------------------------------------------+   
      0             5             10            15            20            25
```

Comment: I too was able to get all the points to be displayed by either playing with a offset or size. But, the problem is i generate a huge set of graphs from a script based on dynamic data fetched during each run of the script. Hence, there is on single(or relatively single value)value for size which works for all the cases. Also, modifying the size makes the graphs looks ugly in certain cases. Thanks for your suggestion anyways.